# Numpy add.at analogue for Numba

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numba

Numba doesnt support add.at function. So I need to find vectorized analog to work with Numba in case then index array have duplicates

```
a=np.ones((10,))
x=np.array([1,2,3,1,4,5])
b=np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1])
np.add.at(a,x,b)
a
array([ 1.,  3.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

If "+=" used:

```
a1=np.ones((10,))
a1[x]+=b
a1
array([ 1.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

there is mistake in a1[1] = 2, but corrected value is 3.

Comment: If you only need the 1D case, a jitted `for i in range(len(x)): a[x[i]] += b[i]` is ~50x faster than `np.add.at` for larger arrays.

Comment: `add.at` is needed in `numpy` because `+=` is buffered and doesn't handle duplicates in an iterative fashion.  You don't need that in `numba`, where plain iteration is fast enough.